# Lookup value inside dictionary-of-dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, python-requests, twitch

I'm creating a Python application where you input a Twitch emote name, and it spits out a link to the image. (i.e.; If I input "Kappa", the result will be a link to [this](http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/25/1.0)) I can use an API to get the emote name and id, but the entries in the returned JSON are formatted as such:

```
"id":{"code": "emote name","channel":"channel name", "set":"set number"}
```

What I want to get is a dictionary like such:

```
{"emote name": "id", "emote name": "id"...}
```

I've tried plenty of methods (parsing as XML, key-value pairs), and nothing has worked. Here's my code so far:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://twitchemotes.com/api_cache/v2/images.json")
# Here, I'd handle the JSON from the response; however I don't know how.
query_name = input("Enter emote name:")
for k,v in emote_dict.items()
  if k == query_name:
    response = "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/" + v + "/1.0"
print("Here you go: " + response)
```

Comment: You can't have a dictionary like `{"emote name": "id", "emote name": "id"...}` because of the duplicate keys. You probably want a list of dictionaries: i.e. `[{"emote name": "id"}, {"emote name": "id"},...]` or maybe just a list of id's: `["id1", "id2', ...]`.

Comment: @martineau I meant like     {"Kappa": "25", "anomHeart": "34442"...} where "emote name" was what you type in the chat, and id was the number part of the url to the photo.

Comment: OK. Where's the definition of `emote_dict`?

Comment: I would define emote_dict when I parse the response got from the unofficial API. I guess I should have noted that the result of parsing the JSON would be stored in emote_dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using a [dict comprehension](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/04/dictionary-comprehensions-in-python.html) to create the dictionary you want:

```
emote_dict ={value.get('code'):emote_id for (emote_id, value) in r.json()['images'].iteritems()}
query_name = raw_input("Enter emote name:").strip()
if query_name in emote_dict:
    response = "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/" + emote_dict[query_name] + "/1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.7 or 3.0 and above:

If you have the JSON like

```
response = {"id": {"code": "emote name", "channel": "channel name", "set": "set number"},  ... }
```

Try it with [dict comprehension](http://intermediatepythonista.com/python-comprehensions) like so:

```
{val["code"]: id_ for id_, val in response.items()}
```

It remaps the responded JSON to be a new dict of form

```
{emote name: id, emote name: id, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already downloaded images.json to your local file system (i.e., it doesn't change too frequently):

```
import json

with open('/path/to/images.json') as f_in:
    orig_json = json.loads(f_in.read())

emote_dict = {value['code']: key for key, value in orig_json['images'].items()}
```

Comment: Would be nice, but images.json is too big to have a local copy of (i.e; Python freezes when I try to open a file containing it.)

Comment: Really? That's very unusal. It's only 2MB.

Comment: I don't know, but IDLE does freeze when I try to read() the file. Command prompt is the only python on my system that can show "images.json".

Answer (score 0):

Since the JSON data of the response looks something like this:

```
{
    "images": {
        "11540": {
            "code": "getvexxedGetvexxed",
            "set": 3483,
            "channel": "vexxgaming"
        },
        "11541": {
            "code": "makMak",
            "set": 3515,
            "channel": "morninafterkill"
          .
          .
          .
        "38346": {
            "code": "cynicalWeasel",
            "set": 634,
            "channel": "totalbiscuit"
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "generated_at": "2015-08-25T02:30:11Z"
    }
}
```

You could create the `emote_dict` dictionary like you say you want with a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) expression like the last line of this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://twitchemotes.com/api_cache/v2/images.json")
emote_dict = {v["code"]: k for k, v in response.json()["images"].items()}
```

And use it like this:

```
query_name = input("Enter emote name:")
id = emote_dict.get(query_name)
if not id:
    print('{} emote name not found'.format(query_name))
else:
    image_link= "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/" + id + "/1.0"
    print("Here you go: " + image_link)
```